# Angularjs, How to assign factory return value to multiple scope

Tags: angularjs

I have two forms in single page one for reference and one for actual data entry. I assigned a factory return value to two scope but when I change a value of scope serviceData , value of serviceDataRef also change

```
wsp.getSearviceAreaData()
 .success(function(data) {
    $scope.serviceData = data;
    $scope.serviceDataRef = data;
})
```

but when i assign scope by calling factory two time it will work

```
wsp.getSearviceAreaData()
 .success(function(data) {
    $scope.serviceData = data;
})
wsp.getSearviceAreaData()
 .success(function(data) {
    $scope.serviceDataRef = data;
})
```

what might be the problem please help

Comment: does it make difference?? it will call in page load

Comment: if you call it in js load then what do you mean by "but when I change a value of scope serviceData , value of serviceDataRef also change"?

Comment: <tr ng-repeat="sv in serviceData"><td><input type="text" ng-model="sv.name"></td></tr>
<tr ng-repeat="sv_ref in serviceDataRef"><td><input type="text" ng-model="sv_ref.name"></td></tr>

Comment: here when i change name of sv.name , name of sv_ref.name also change

Comment: you want to change it or are you saying that sv_ref.name changing if you change sv.name??make a plunker please

Comment: yes sv_ref.name is changing how do i prevent